# Match an variant name string in a sentence with regex in python3

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-3.8

I want to match `c.[1210-12t[7];1408a>g]` in the below text in python3 with regex:

`It was frequently associated with the c.[1210-12t[7];1408a>g] (t7-p.val470) allele and this cftr genetic background could not explain the putative pathogenicity of this variant.`

But I only know the prefix `c.[1210-12t[7]` of the required word according to the scenario. Thus, I tried regex pattern `c\.\[1210-12t\[7\].*\b` but it matches half of the sentence:

`c.[1210-12t[7];1408a>g] (t7-p.val470) allele and this cftr genetic background could not explain the putative pathogenicity of this variant.`

Could you help me to fix my regex?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matching of `.*` is the culprit as it will match everything as much as possible. Since what you are trying to capture doesn't have spaces, you could just capture until the space part by using the non-greedy form `.*?` up until the earliest space `\s` or end of string `$`.

```
c\..*?\s
```

Or if it could be the last part of the sentence:

```
c\..*?(?:\s|$)
```

Or if you want to capture the group:

```
(c\..*?)(?:\s|$)
```

**Sample run:**
[image]

Where:

- Outer `(...)` - Capture the group
- `c` - Match the letter "c"
- `\.` - Match the period character
- `.*?` - Match any character in a non-greedy way
- Outer `(?:...)` - Non-capturing group
- `\s|$` - Match either the space character or the end of the string. Since the earlier pattern is non-greedy, then this will match the earliest possible space character.

Comment: works for me! To remove the earliest space from the match, I would try `c\.\[1210-12t\[7\].*?(?:\s|$)` or just strip(" ") the match result. Thank you very much!
But I don't know why `\b` cannot match the boundary (the earliest space).